# testcontainers fails to start with maven on mac m1

Tags: java, maven, apple-m1, testcontainers

I am trying to create testcontainers and they are failing with below errors

Inside the container

```
[2022-08-16 07:22:52,694] INFO 172.29.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2022:07:22:52 +0000] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 404 49  21 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
[2022-08-16 07:22:53,708] ERROR Request Failed with exception  (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
```

On the logs

```
12:41:07.851 [main] ERROR  [confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0] - Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [57338] should be listening)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:90)
```

This is my implementation

```
public class SchemaRegistryContainer extends GenericContainer<SchemaRegistryContainer> {
  private static final int SCHEMA_PORT = 8081;

  public SchemaRegistryContainer(String version) {
    super("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:" + version);
    withExposedPorts(8081);
    waitStrategy = Wait
        .forHttp("/info")
        .forStatusCode(200)
        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5));
  }
}
```

**Here is environment details**

OS : `MacBook Air (M1, 2020) Version 12.1 Apple M1`

Java version : `openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14`

`<testcontainers.version>1.17.2</testcontainers.version>`

`<testcontainers.junit-jupiter.version>1.17.2</testcontainers.junit-jupiter.version>`

Comment: Have you checked if that port already has something running?

Comment: Yes nothing is already running on that port.

Comment: Are you sure that this service have `/info` endpoint. If I found the proper documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html They don't have such

Comment: Yeah Service didn't have `/info` endpoint. Nice catch thanks.

Comment: @ЕмилиянЙорданов Would you like to write this an answer? Then it can be accepted an upvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if schema registry service from `confluent platform` has `/info` endpoint.

Reference : https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html